# JavaScript Objects: Property Set but Returns undefined When Accessed

Tags: javascript

Greetings,

I'm working with a JavaScript object that is defined like so:

```
var ytVideoData = new Object();
```

I then assign a value to it inside of a jQuery .ajax():

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xmlproxy.php?url="+ytId+"&mode=native",
    success: function(data) {

        ytVideoData.thumbnail = $(data).find("media\\:thumbnail[yt\\:name='default']").attr("url"); // default thumbnail image
    }
});
```

In another function, I want to access the thumbnail property I just set. However, when I do:

```
function addPlaylistItem(tumblrUser, videoData) {
    console.log(videoData.thumbnail);
}
```

All I get in the console is "undefined". When I do:

```
console.log(videoData);
```

I get the entire object logged to the console and can see the thumbnail property properly set inside of the object like so:

http://mp3.deceast.com/js-objectissue.jpg

After trying several different methods I just can't seem to get it work. How do I access this object property?

Comment: you know how asynchrous callbacks work right?

Comment: Can you show the code that includes the ajax call as well as the `addPlaylistItem()` call? If you're calling `addPlaylistItem()` **after** `$.ajax()`, rather than **inside of the `success` callback**, this **will not work** because the request is **asynchronous**. This question gets asked _at least_ once a day on SO.

Comment: Are you positive that the success function in the ajax call is executing before your other function?

Comment: One other thing: no need for `new Object()`. Just write `var ytVideoData = {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A callback via ajax is asychronous. WHich means you can't tell when it will run the success function.

The order that is probably happening is

```
$.ajax
addPlaylistItem // undefined
success // defined
```

Try calling the function in the success postback

```
success: function(data) {
    ytVideoData.thumbnail = $(data).find("media\\:thumbnail[yt\\:name='default']").attr("url"); // default thumbnail image
    addPlaylistItem(getTumblrUser(), ytVideoData);
}
```

Comment: I've tried setting the async property to false on the ajax call and it still behaves the same. The part I'm confused about is that when I log the entire object to the console, I can see the property being set properly, but when I log the object property itself it appears as undefined.

Comment: @Matt: could you post a link that reproduces the behavior, and/or a more complete code sample that shows how the ajax call relates to how you're trying to call `addPlaylistItem()`? Are you sure you're passing the correct object to `addPlaylistItem()`?

Comment: @MattR never use async false. It is bad! Check how you cann addPlaylistItem it may be a bug there

Comment: Looks like it was an error without my code has been structured. I moved the addPlaylistItem() call inside of the callback and everything is behaving as expected. Thanks to everyone who chimed in so quickly, SO is an amazing community!